# How To Create A Hash That Can Be Read In PHP And C#?

Tags: c#, php, hash, base64, sha512

The project in question is a simple REST interface over HTTPS.  I'm trying to hash the data being passed so I can make sure it hasn't been modified during transport (using a salt, of course).  However, there seems to be something wrong with my code.  The REST server is PHP, and the client is C#.

PHP

```
public function hash($text)
{
    $text = utf8_encode($text);
    $encrypted = hash("sha512", $text);
    return base64_encode($encrypted);
}
```

C#

```
public static string Hash(string Plaintext)
{
    byte[] HashValue, MessageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Plaintext);

    SHA512Managed SHhash = new SHA512Managed();

    HashValue = SHhash.ComputeHash(MessageBytes);

    return Convert.ToBase64String(HashValue);
}
```

These do not produce the same hash.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the 3 steps and comparing the output?

Comment: Maybe your source data is already different. C# and PHP use different types for your input data. Are you sure the actual binary content of both is exactly same BEFORE you hash them?

Comment: make sure that the utf8 encoding is absolutely identical BEFORE hashing. sha512 is sha512, so if you get different hashes, you've got different inputs.

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem you should be posting it as an answer, rather than as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 2):

As per [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20357989/2) by the OP, this is the solution:

> First, hash in PHP
>   returns hexadecimal by default, whereas C# returns the raw data. 
>   Ended up needing to change `hash("sha512", $text)` to `hash("sha512",
>   $text, true)`.  Secondly, `utf8_encode` doesn't appear to do the same
>   thing as C#'s `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`; when I switched
>   `utf8_encode($text)` to `mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-16LE')` and
>   `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` to `new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes`, the
>   hashes began to match up.
>
> In short, the final working code is:
>
> PHP
>
> ```
> public function hash($text)
> {
>     $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-16LE');
>     $encrypted = hash("sha512", $text, true);
>     return base64_encode($encrypted);
> }
> ```
>
> C#
>
> ```
> public static string Hash(string Plaintext)
> {
>     byte[] HashValue, MessageBytes = new UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(Plaintext);
>
>     SHA512Managed SHhash = new SHA512Managed();
>
>     HashValue = SHhash.ComputeHash(MessageBytes);
>
>     return Convert.ToBase64String(HashValue);
> }
> ```

Comment: Don't forget to dispose your `SHA512Managed` object after use. Consider using `using`.